# Jest in Node JS

Tags: jestjs

I installed jest on my node js project with : npm install --save-dev jest.

I added jest in the script of package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node app/index.js",
   "dev": "nodemon app/index.js",
   "test": "jest"
}
```

I try launching jest with the commande: npm run test but I always get this error:

PS P:\Projets Angular\dblogwebapp\back-end> npm run test

```
> back-end@1.0.0 test
> jest

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, realpath 'myPath\back-end'
at Function.realpathSync.native (node:fs:2550:3)
at tryRealpath (myPath\back-end\node_modules\jest-util\build\tryRealpath.js:26:39)
at Object.<anonymous> (myPath\back-end\node_modules\jest-resolve\build\resolver.js:124:49)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (myPath\back-end\node_modules\jest-resolve\build\index.js:9:40)
```

Can anyone help me plz. thanks

Comment: I tried following it to find the exact ligne that makes the error.
After some console.log I found the cause it's in this ligne :
resolvedCwd = (0, _jestUtil().tryRealpath)(process.cwd());

in the file node_modules/jet-resolve/build/resolver.js

when I put this ligne in a try block it gives this error:

Comment: Validation Error:

  Module P:\Projets Angular\tester-back-end\node_modules\jest-circus\runner.js in the testRunner option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: P:\Projets Angular\tester-back-end

Comment: Did u get the solution?